# Incorrect rpm version comparison by yum for dependencies

Tags: yum, rhel, rpmbuild, rhel7, rpm-spec

This is a RHEL 7.4 system.

I have two rpms - *a* and *b*. *a-1-0* is installed. *b-1-0* and *a-2-0* are in my local repository created using the command `createrepo $PWD` followed by `yum-config-manager --add-repo=file://$PWD`.

*b-1-0* has `Requires: a > 1` in its spec file

*a-1-0* has an explicit `Provides: a` in its spec file. This is a mistake in *a-1-0* spec file introduced many years back.

I want *a-1-0* to be replaced with *a-2-0* when I execute `yum install b`. However, *yum* installs *b-1-0* without upgrading *a-1-0* to *a-2-0*. For some reason, yum seems to think that *a-1-0* satisfies the `a > 1` requirement. Is there a way to solve this problem without making any change to *b.spec* or explicitly passing *a-2-0* to `yum install` ?

**Update**

```
bash$ rpm -qp --provides a-1-0.x86_64.rpm
a
a = 1-0
a(x86-64) = 1-0

bash$ rpm -qp --provides a-2-0.x86_64.rpm
a = 2-0
a(x86-64) = 2-0

bash$ rpm -qp --requires b-1-0.x86_64.rpm
a >= 2
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(PayloadIsLzma) <= 4.4.6-1
```

Comment: you could look exactly at what is provided / required by your packages: `rpm -qp b-1-0.rpm --requires` and `rpm -q a --provides` to see why yum is happy just installing b. That being said; I am quite sure there won't be any solution without changing your yum command or b.spec

Comment: @ChrisMaes , *b-1-0* requires `a >= 2`, `rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1`, `rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1` and `rpmlib(PayloadIsLzma) <= 4.4.6-1` .  *a-1-0* provides `a`, `a = 1-0` and `a(x86-64) = 1-0`. *a-2-0* provides `a = 2-0` and `a(x86-64) = 2-0`.

Comment: Update your question and include the output (exactly) of these commands.  `rpm -qp --provides a*.rpm`, `rpm -qp --provides b*.rpm`, `rpm -qp --requires b*.rpm`.